# Tag synonyms on [Meta]:

Tags: discussion, support, tag-synonyms, meta

I have a few tag synonym suggestions:

[vote](/questions/tagged/vote) -> [votes](/questions/tagged/votes)

[fair-use](/questions/tagged/fair-use) -> [copyright](/questions/tagged/copyright)

[synonym-request](/questions/tagged/synonym-request) -> [tag-synonyms](/questions/tagged/tag-synonyms)

And a question, why are some of the tags 'moderator' and a few of the tags 'moderation'?

[moderation-tools](/questions/tagged/moderation-tools) -> [moderator-tools](/questions/tagged/moderator-tools)

[moderation-history](/questions/tagged/moderation-history) -> ?

e.g. Should there be a [moderator-history](/questions/tagged/moderator-history)??

Comment: Fair Use and Copyright are not the same thing.  Fair Use is an aspect of Copyright.

Comment: Moderator-tools exist because that's what it's called.  Moderation-history exists because that's what it is called.

Comment: I see.  I am not a mod.  Just trying to clean up the tags a bit.  Please answer @Robert and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

random made [vote](/questions/tagged/vote) a synonym of [votes](/questions/tagged/votes), and [moderation-tools](/questions/tagged/moderation-tools) a synonym of [moderator-tools](/questions/tagged/moderator-tools).
As said by Robert Harvey, *fair use* and *copyright* have two different meanings, and making [fair-use](/questions/tagged/fair-use) a synonym of [copyright](/questions/tagged/copyright) doesn't make sense; [moderation-history](/questions/tagged/moderation-history) is used because *Moderation history* is the name used in the user interface (as far as I remember, from my experience as pro-tempore moderator).