# Tag synonyms: tag-synonyms and synonym-request

Tags: discussion, support, tag-synonyms, meta, synonym-request

The two tags [tag-synonyms](/questions/tagged/tag-synonyms) and [synonym-request](/questions/tagged/synonym-request) have almost identical tag wikis and seem to be equivalent. Should not one become synonym of the other then? I found this question: [Tag synonyms on [Meta]:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96985/tag-synonyms-on-meta) which asked for it but there was no specific comment/reaction to it.

Based on the usage it should probably go [synonym-request](/questions/tagged/synonym-request) -> [tag-synonyms](/questions/tagged/tag-synonyms)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think they are synonymous:

- [tag-synonyms](/questions/tagged/tag-synonyms) is meant for discussion/support issues about tag synonyms (i.e. how they work, what they are for, who can create them, ...).
- [synonym-request](/questions/tagged/synonym-request) is specifically for requesting a new synonym relationship

All tag synonym questions need not be synonym requests. (And I don't think [tag-synonyms](/questions/tagged/tag-synonyms) would necessarily be appropriate for synonym requests.)

Comment: Nuts. Beat me by 34 seconds.

Comment: Then the tag wiki for tag-synonyms should be changed as it is frequently used for synonym requests and it is not clear from the tag wiki what it should be used for

Comment: @ChrisWue: feel free to [propose a better wording for it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/2917).